# Servicenow requirement UI button

Tags: servicenow, servicenow-rest-api

When I click on UI action button, it should pop-up a custom dialog box and it should show some fields getting from incident_task. After this by clicking a confirm UI action button, it should create a new record/task.

how can this be done with OnSubmit client script?

Answer (score 0):

You can pop up a dialog window that will display a UI page you created in the system.
The ui page is in jelly so you'll have to configure that to display the needed information and buttons